# removing newline characers ,but leaving some

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have data in the following format

```
45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 
45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 
45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 

45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 
45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 

45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550
```

where there are newline characters after 7 sets of 8 characters and also new line characters between blocks of text.

I want to remove the newlines within a block of text but leave the gaps between the blocks, so that it ends up looking like

```
45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550     45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 

45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 

45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simplified example:

```
$ cat file
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

1 2 3
4 5 6

1 2 3
```

The following will solve your problem:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NF?OFS:RS RS)}1' file
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

1 2 3 4 5 6 

1 2 3
```

**Explanation:**

The output record separator `ORS` defines how records should be separated on output. We either set the value of `ORS` to be `OFS` or `RS RS` depending on the number of fields on the current line. `OFS` is the output field separator which by default is a space and `RS` is the input record separator which by default is a newline character. The trailing 1 is just an `awk` idiom to print the current record.

Comment: amazing!! can you explain it?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ printf("%s", NF ? $0 : "\n\n") } END { if(NF) print "" }' file
```

Output:

```
45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 

45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 

45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550 45280550
```

Comment: This concatenates records with out spaces between them.

Comment: @sudo_O His posted data has spaces on the last.

Comment: @matthewmeacham I hope you try mine as well.

Comment: What about the duplicate printing of the final record tho?

Comment: @sudo_O Corrected. It seems that $0 is printed along if print has no arguments. I never knew that.